# Spring Condition - Get information about the bean being created

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to conditionally create Spring Beans using the `Condition` interface

`public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata)`

I'd like to know what Bean is currently being processed at the point that the condition is called, as I'd like to call a static method on it. Is it possible to get the name of the Bean being created from either the context or metadata parameter? I've had a quick look using a debugger and didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: In the short term I've fixed it by using metadata.toSring(), but that feels a little dirty

Answer (score 1):

As the `Condition` can be applied on the class or a bean method , so `AnnotatedTypeMetadata` can be in the type of `ClassMetadata` or `MethodMetadata`.

A more proper way to get the class of the bean that is being processed is from `AnnotatedTypeMetadata`:

```java
if (metadata instanceof ClassMetadata) {
    ClassMetadata classMetadata = (ClassMetadata) metadata;
    String className =  classMetadata.getClassName();
}
```

Once you know the class , you can get its bean name by :

```java
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf = context.getBeanFactory();
String[] beanNames = bf.getBeanNamesForType(Class.forName(className));
```

And once you knows its bean name , you can get more info of this bean by :

```java
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf = context.getBeanFactory();
BeanDefinition bd = bf.getBeanDefinition(someBeanName);
```